# How to find the line begins with digit and move digit to previous line in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

For example:

```
Rahul
1423502012
Manage
```

Should be converted to:

```
Rahul 1423502012
Manage
```

I have thousands of lines, please help me to move the number (eg.1423502012) at the end of previous line.

Answer (score 1):

In Notepad++, do a regex Find-and-Replace:

Find what:

```
^(.*)\s+^(\d+)
```

Replace with:

```
$1 $2
```

Make sure to uncheck the box next to ". matches newline".

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R(?=\d)`
- Replace with:    (a space)
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R          : any kind of linebreak
(?=\d)      : lookahead, make sure we have a digit after current position
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Rahul 1423502012
Manage
```